# In Intellij, no clickable links to file in stack trace

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, stack-trace, clickable

In my Java project, the stack trace in the debug console no longer offers clickable links to the source file, seemingly without any reason. Although clickable links are still present in the stack trace of my other IntelliJ projects, I am unsure of any changes that may have caused this issue in the current project. I have tried invalidate caches, removed .idea folder but not helpful.

invalidate caches, removed .idea folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-316353/Stack-traces-in-log-console-do-not-work-as-source-links).

The fix [is available](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/IDEA-A-2100661425/IntelliJ-IDEA-2023.1-Latest-Builds) in 2023.1.1+ versions.

If it's not the case, please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with a sample project to reproduce the issue.